# Allow code after a bugged line to continue without use of try and catch

Tags: unity, c#

My problem is with C# in unity, but I think the problem can be applied to all coding languages.

For example I have a start function/event that may initiate many things. Some lines of code may issue a bug but I want to allow new lines of code run after that without having to encapsulate every line of code with try and catch. Is there any common solution for this that I'm missing?

Comment: What kind of bug are we hacking around here? Could we just fix the bug instead?

Comment: @DMGregory some unpredicted exceptions. I think it better explains

Comment: You might want to read up on [offensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_programming). Simply ignoring an error is almost always a bad idea. When there is an error, you want your code to fail fast and spectacularly so you can easily find and correct the bug.

Comment: I’m Visual Basic there’s the always-terrible `in error resume next` so that does exist in some language, although not in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Try-Catch blocks are the way to go.

It tells the compiler to trap exceptions and resume after the block, making sure operations are serialised properly to resume execution and not reordered for better performance.

It's not feasible to restore an execution context to resume execution properly otherwise.